# .NET Core Web API: Possible to assign controller route in appsettings.json config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

I'd like my Web API controller's route to be assigned dynamically via the config file (appsettings.json).

I figured maybe it would be a simple solution. However, trying this [unsurprisingly] doesn't work:

```
private static string route = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Path");

[Route(route)]
// action
```

Which results in `An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression, or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type`

Is it possible do do what I desire? If so, what are the best practices for doing so? I can't find much documentation on it, and would prefer not to roll my own `HttpListener` to accomplish a relatively simple goal.

Comment: There is convention based and attribute based routing. for attribute based routing the route template is a constant. For what you want to do you would have to create your own routing to override the built in framework.

Comment: @Nkosi Thank you. Could you shoot me an article or something going over some keywords to research?

Comment: Documentation Reference [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I was overthinking things.

In `Startup`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // basic stuff
    var config = services.GetService<IConfiguration>();
    string route = config.GetValue<string>("Path");

    app.UseMvc(routes => {
        routes.MapRoute("someName", route, new { controller = "myController", action = "myAction"});
    });
}
```

Easy as pie.

Comment: Yeah, that happens sometimes.